# What information is required for other app developer to call my app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing some digital signature application. Some other app developer is going to use my app. I wonder what information I need to tell them.

Do I just need to tell the package and class names?

Or should I tell them to call through intent filter, so give them custom action and category?

And I surely need to inform them of the requestCode below, isn't it?

startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)

I also saw some web site calling the installed app with data to process and return. Is it using the intent?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the AndroidManifest.xml file of your android App to the other development team. This should contain, what kind of intent can call your application. For example,

The intent filters mention the kind of actions they respond to and the data that should be provided on create. If there are multiple apps on device which respond to similar filters the app manager will provide the option to select any of the mentioned applications.